# Particle instance modifier ignoring particle rotation

Tags: particles

I need to use the particle instance modifier to make an object be emitted that bends with the hair of the particle system. Think leaves being emitted and bending along the hair curve. Only thing that doesn't work is that I can't get the "leaves" to always face upwards, adjusting the rotation options in the particle system appears to have no effect. The z-rotation of the leaves always seems random no matter what. How can I make it so that the leaves are always facing upwards?

[image]

I am using Blender 2.79b